# Как перенести текст в кнопке? нужно чтобы код работал на js

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var _btn1 = document.createElement('button'); // создание кнопки

_btn1.id = '_cmd1'; // её id
_btn1.textContent = "Привет" + '\n' + "Мир" // хочу перенести текст привет мир чтобы в не в одной строке был
document.body.appendChild(_btn1); // нужно чтобы кнопка создалась
_btn1.onclick = function() { // при клике на кнопку 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button><div>Привет</div><div>мир</div></button>
```

Создайте(добавьте) этот код на js.
И ещё. `AppendChild()` нужен чтобы добавить элемент в контейнер, а создаёт его `createElement`

Comment: вы на html5 написали? нужно на js

Comment: Всё ответ принмается

Comment: @Ivan912 писал исходя из того, что вы умеете создавать элемент)